Overlay Application Windows for Tiling WMs (Awesome)
System Information:
$ inxi -S
System:
  Host: ... Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: awesome v: 4.3 Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma

I currently try to optimize my workflow and I am hooked with tiling wms. Currently I look into awesome, which is great out of the box, but I think there is still a lot of configuration ahead.
One thing I miss, is a way to temporarily show an application window, i.e. quickly show a calculator, a note taking app, a terminal or the likes, without messing up my tiling. A bit like the tilda terminal, but more flexible.
My idea is: I press a keyboard shortcut (or on a button on a bar, whatever), and a window overlays my desktop, has focus, I interact with it and when I am done it vanishes again (without closing the application, keeping it's state) and I can continue working with my original window arrangement.
Beeing done could be indicated by another shortcut or (less perfect) by the window loosing focus.
Currently, when I need some application like that, and it is a shell application, I open a new terminal, restore the screen session, then close it - but this always rearranges my "tiles" and I am limited to cli applications.
So, what I am looking for is:

Either a way to configure awesomewm for that behavior
Another tiling wm that would support such behavior
An additional application, providing such feature
Hints for the correct terminology, enabling me to help myself



It's been years since I used linux and awesome as my main OS and WM. I am definitely misusing terminology, which limits my googling success. 2. I am new to this community. I hope my question satisfies standards and is on-topic.

